# Joomla alters the template code

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

just run into one interesting problem.

Joomla 3.6.2 somehow alters the template's index.php file creating weird results displaying the page.

The original part of the code from index.php is this:

```
<div id="content">
        <div id="main_content">
            <div id="breakingnews">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breakingnews" style="xhtml"  />
            </div>
            <div id="news_module">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="news_module" style="xhtml"  />
            </div>
            <div id="component_wrapper">
                <jdoc:include type="message" />
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
            </div>
            <div id="content_module">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content_module" style="xhtml"  />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div id="inner_right">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="xhtml"  />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="breadcrumbs">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumbs" style="xhtml"  />
        </div>
        <div id="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

Joomla creates this code:
[DIV #right is within #main_content DIV but it is not supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqOMd.png)

Same thing also happens in other parts of the website, for example, within items in blog layout; it puts .item and .span elements inside each other like this: [By that it makes the whole website layout go crazy!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQtJa.png)

Any ideas, guys??

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like whatever is in your `component_wrapper` is adding an extra `</div>` as the `content_module` div is also inside it too. Have you checked the code of your component? But anyway, it's because of a closing tag. So Joomla isn't doing anything to your code, but a component is probably coded wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have different number of open and close `<div>` tags in your component's template (article?)
Can you take a look at /templates/your_default_template/html/com_content/article/ [if you rebuild it]

Or try 'view-source' in FireFox - it marks unclosed tags with red color [ctrl+u] (I'm not sure if Chrome or Edge marks it?)